# Why move top when use onEndReached function in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello I am implementing a list through React-native. My problem now is that when the list comes to the end, a function that loads a new list is called, and the list keeps moving back to the top. What is the problem??

use EvaluationList

```js
          <EvaluationList
            sort={sort}
            rkey={rkey}
            onRefresh={() => {
              applyRkey();
            }}
            useLikeContext
            onScrollPosition={(e) => setScrollTop(e.top / 16 >= 5.725)}
            ListHeaderComponent={
              <Div className={'list-header'}>
                <Div className={`eva-filter pah-2`}>
                  <Btn className={'eval-category-button'} onClick={handleSortChange}>
                    <Img className={'eval-category-icon'} src="/img/icon-down.png" />
                    <Span className={'eval-category-text'}>{ORDER_VALUES[sort]}</Span>
                  </Btn>
                  <Link href={'/evaluation/search'}>
                    <Btn className={'icon-exclusive-button'}>
                      <Img className={'i-contain'} src="/img/icon-search.png" />
                    </Btn>
                  </Link>
                </Div>
              </Div>
            }
          />
```

EvaluationList component

```js
const EvaluationList = React.memo((props) => {
  const { position } = useSelector((s) => s.auth, shallowEqual);
  const { keyword, sort, searchMode, useLikeContext, rkey, ListHeaderComponent, onScrollPosition, onRefresh } = props;
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const [offset, setOffset] = useState({ distance: 1, page: 0 });
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const hide_rate_at = useRef();
  const onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = useRef();
  const onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentumLength = useRef();
  const isReload = useRef();
  const scroll = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current = true;
    onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentumLength.current = 0;
    isReload.current = false;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    hide_rate_at.current = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  }, [rkey]);

  const loadData = async (distance, page, sort, keyword) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await mgApi.get(`/menus`, {
        params: {
          rkey,
          distance,
          page,
          keyword,
          tpl: `eva_${sort}`,
          hide_rate_at: sort === 'search' ? '' : hide_rate_at.current,
          lat: position?.lat,
          lng: position?.lng,
        },
      });

      if (isReload.current) {
        onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentumLength.current = 0;
      }

      onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentumLength.current += data.items.length;

      setOffset({ distance, page });
      if (data?.total_elements === 0) {
        loadData(distance + 1, 0, sort, keyword);
      } else if (page === 0 && distance === 1) {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {

        if (isReload.current) {
          setData(data);
          isReload.current = false;
        } else {
          setData((x) => ({ ...data, items: (x?.items || []).concat(data.items) }));
        }

        if (onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentumLength.current < 8) {
          loadData(distance + 1, 0, sort, keyword);
        } else {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
  };

  const handleEndReached = async () => {
    if (loading) return;

    if (!onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current) {
      if (!data?.has_next) {
        loadData(offset.distance + 1, 0, sort, keyword).catch(console.warn);
      } else {
        loadData(offset.distance, offset.page + 1, sort, keyword).catch(console.warn);
      }
    }
    onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current = true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!searchMode || (searchMode && keyword)) {
      setLoading(true);
      if (scroll.current) scroll.current?.scrollToOffset?.({ y: 0 });
      loadData(1, 0, sort, keyword).catch(console.warn);
    }
  }, [keyword, sort, rkey]);

  return (
    <FlatList
      key={`eva-body-scroll-${rkey}-${onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentumLength.current}`}
      ref={scroll}
      id={'eva-list'}
      onRefresh={() => {
        if (onRefresh) {
          hide_rate_at.current = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
          isReload.current = true;
          onRefresh();
        } else {
          isReload.current = true;
          setLoading(true);
          loadData(1, 0, sort, keyword).catch(console.warn);
        }
      }}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
      onMomentumScrollBegin={() => {
        onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum.current = false;
      }}
      refreshing={loading}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      className={'eval-menu-section'}
      data={data?.items && !searchMode ? [null, ...data?.items] : data?.items || []}
      onScrollPosition={onScrollPosition}
      contentContainerStyle={'eval-menu-section-inner'}
      keyExtractor={(item) => `${item?.id}`}
      onEndReached={handleEndReached}
      stickyHeaderIndices={ListHeaderComponent ? [0] : []}
      ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
      ListEmptyComponent={keyword && !loading && <NotFound message={'메뉴 검색 결과가 없습니다.'} />}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
        !searchMode && index === 0 ? (
          <Div className={'h1rem background-white'} />
        ) : (
          <MenuForPoint
            rkey={rkey}
            data={item}
            useLikeContext={useLikeContext}
            onChange={(item) => {
              setData(
                produce((draft) => {
                  draft.items[index - (data?.items && !searchMode ? 1 : 0)].user_rate = item.user_rate;
                  draft.items[index - (data?.items && !searchMode ? 1 : 0)].user_actions = item.user_actions;
                }),
              );
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
});

export default EvaluationList;
```

Flatlist Component

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { StyleContext } from '@common/contexts/StyleProvider';

const CFlatList = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const context = useContext(StyleContext);
  const {
    items,
    data,
    renderItem,
    className,
    contentContainerStyle,
    onScrollPosition,
    onScroll,
    keyExtractor,
    scrollEventThrottle,
    ...oProps
  } = props;

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    onScrollPosition?.({
      top: e?.nativeEvent?.contentOffset?.y,
      left: e?.nativeEvent?.contentOffset?.x,
    });
    onScroll?.(e);
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      {...oProps}
      ref={ref}
      data={items || data}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={context?.getStyle?.(className)}
      contentContainerStyle={context?.getStyle?.(contentContainerStyle)}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor || ((item, index) => (item?.id ? String(item?.id) : String(index)))}
      onScroll={handleScroll}
      scrollEventThrottle={scrollEventThrottle || 1}
    />
  );
});

export default CFlatList;
```